Is $n\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/(m/n)\mathbb{Z} $ as rings?
Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that $n$ divides $m$. Is it true that
$$
n\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/(m/n)\mathbb{Z}
$$
as rings. I believe it suffices to show that $n\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ has an identity which amounts to showing that there exists a $0 < r < m/n$ such that $m$ divides $nr(nr-1)$.
Any help or hints will be highly appreciated.

You probably meant this statement.

No. For example, $2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. In $2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ every element squares to zero, so there's no identity.
